# How may I get Visual Studio Incremental Search to show some lines above and below the target?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When Incremental Search (CTRL+I) moves to its target line, it often scrolls to put the line at the top or bottom of the window., hiding adjacent lines from view. Its there any way to get it to include e.g. 5 lines above and below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the default search function can't be customized that way. What I would recommend is that you install the Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools. They include some really, **really** awesome features including a completely overhauled search system that (as far as I can tell) pulls results as close to the centre of the window as possible.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Unfortunately if you're using an express edition of VS, this won't help you as they don't support extensions :(

Comment: Just as a side-note, the power tools are included as standard in the upcoming VS11 which should include express :)

Comment: Thanks - looking forward to that!